# Epsilon delta definition of limit of function

Tags: real-analysis

[why for this to be meaningful it is necessary that c to be a limit point of the domain. If c is not a limit point then what will happen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsnEQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If $c$ is not a limit point of $D$, then there is $ \delta >0$ such that $|x-c|> \delta$ for all $x \in D$. Then you can not approximate the point $c$ with points $x \in D$.

Comment: Please give an example

Comment: Let $D=[0,2] $ and $c=3$

Comment: Might be good also with an example where $c$ is a limit point but not contained in $D$: $D = [0, 2)$ and $c=2$.